# Backup on Share NFS fails - Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, backup, nfs

I've a network disk where backups are stored every night, but after some hour the backup fails with the following error:

> Executing the query "BACKUP DATABASE [foo] TO  DISK = N'\\XXX.XX.XX...." failed with the following error: "Cannot open backup device '\\XXX.XX.XX.XX\vol\BACKUP\BACKUP\foo\foo_backup_2019_07_04_010253_4929321.bak'. Operating system error 1450(Insufficient System Resources Exist to Complete the Requested Service.).

or else:

> ...failed: 121(the semaphore timeout period has expired.)

To mount this share NFS i've used this command:

```
mount -o mtype=hard XXX.XX.XX.XX:/vol/BACKUP T:
```

then in registry editor i've created two DWORD values (AnonymousUid and AnonymousGid) set to 0.

I've tried also to increase KeepAliveTime registry setting but it was uncessful.

If i modify the backup job in SQL Server Management Studio to store to a local disk (eg. D:) it runs without problem but then a free space problem will be raised.

There is something i can do to solve my problem?

Hope everything is clear

Comment: Hi, if you run the backup locally, and then copy the file to the NAS does that work ?  I suspect that a temporary file is created while the backup copy to the NAS, and thus load your hard disk for the task

Comment: Copying the backup to the Share NFS works, unfortunately i can't use this solution to solve my problem for several reasons

Answer (score 0):

I think i resolved my problem: 
In Start -> Administrative Tools -> Services for Network File System (NFS) -> Client for NFS -> Right click -> Properties I edit Client Settings by selecting "Use hard mount" and 5 seconds for "Retry range" (The translation could be incorrect because Windows language is italian).